# How can i make a String list from a int list and a String list in haskell

Tags: haskell

For example,

```
numbers = [4,3,1]
floors = ["Dto","Esq","Cent"]
```

The output would be:

```
["Dto","Dto","Dto","Dto","Esq","Esq","Esq","Cent"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `replicate` function which has the form `Int -> a -> [a]`.

For instance:  `replicate 4 "Dto" = ["Dto", "Dto", "Dto", "Dto"]`

Next you can use `zipWith` which has the form `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. And essentially combines the two lists with the replicate function.

For instance: `zipWith replicate numbers floors = [["Dto", "Dto", "Dto", "Dto"],["Esq","Esq","Esq"], ["Cent"]]`

Finally, you can `concat` the results together to get your final output.

```
numbers = [4, 3, 1]
floors = ["Dto", "Esq", "Cent"]

function :: [Int] -> [String] -> [String]
function nums strs = concat (zipWith replicate nums strs)
```